# can´t get field form SVG objects and move them

Tags: jasmine, protractor

I have a page to tests that has objects, SVG, that are added after a click.
This is like:

startbox (added  by default) 
then we can added more obejcts that will be connected by a “brick-connector” (line)

When added, it is created, dynamically a < g > and inside a < svg >, like:

```
<g _ngcontent-c6="" nea-sequence-editor-brick-connector="" _nghost-c8="" ng-reflect-brick-connector="[object Object]"><polyline _ngcontent-c8="" class="line strok1" points="160,120 160,170" style="stroke: rgb(128, 128, 128);"></polyline><polyline _ngcontent-c8="" class="line strok18" points="160,120 160,170" style="stroke: transparent;"></polyline><polygon _ngcontent-c8="" class="line strok1" points="155,165 160,170 165,165" style="stroke: rgb(128, 128, 128); fill: rgb(128, 128, 128);"></polygon></g>

<g _ngcontent-c6="" nea-sequence-editor-brick-connector="" _nghost-c8="" ng-reflect-brick-connector="[object Object]"><polyline _ngcontent-c8="" class="line strok1" points="160,370 160,410" style="stroke: rgb(128, 128, 128);"></polyline><polyline _ngcontent-c8="" class="line strok18" points="160,370 160,410" style="stroke: transparent;"></polyline><polygon _ngcontent-c8="" class="line strok1" points="155,405 160,410 165,405" style="stroke: rgb(128, 128, 128); fill: rgb(128, 128, 128);"></polygon></g>



<g _ngcontent-c6="" nea-sequence-editor-brick="" _nghost-c9="" ng-reflect-item="[object Object]"><!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><svg _ngcontent-c9="" class="nea-svg" x="110" y="20" width="100" height="100" style=""><rect _ngcontent-c9="" class="nea-svg-rect" fill="green" rx="25" ry="25" x="1" y="1" width="98" height="98"></rect><svg _ngcontent-c9="" height="200" width="200"><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="25" y="50">START</text></svg><circle _ngcontent-c9="" class="nea-svg-rect-circle" cx="50" cy="100" r="10"></circle></svg><!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--></g>


<g _ngcontent-c6="" nea-sequence-editor-brick="" _nghost-c9="" ng-reflect-item="[object Object]"><!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><svg _ngcontent-c9="" class="nea-svg" x="60" y="170" width="200" height="200"><rect _ngcontent-c9="" class="nea-svg-rect" rx="10" ry="10" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" x="1" y="1" width="198" height="198" style="stroke: rgba(85, 68, 153, 0.867); stroke-width: 4; fill: rgb(0, 114, 187);"></rect><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="#fff" style="cursor:pointer" x="180" y="20">x</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size: 14px" x="10" y="20">System: AnalyseErrors</text><line _ngcontent-c9="" x1="2" x2="198" y1="30" y2="30" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="stroke: rgba(85, 68, 153, 0.867); stroke-width: 4;"></line><svg _ngcontent-c9="" class="nea-svg-rect-arg" height="200" width="200"><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="130" y="50">Result1</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="10" y="50">Parameter 1 </text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="130" y="70">6</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="10" y="70">Parameter 2: </text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="130" y="90">10</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="10" y="90">Parameter 3: </text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="130" y="110">left</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="10" y="110">Parmeter 4: </text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="130" y="135">Result3</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="10" y="135">Result : </text></svg><line _ngcontent-c9="" x1="2" x2="198" y1="145" y2="145" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="stroke: rgba(85, 68, 153, 0.867); stroke-width: 4;"></line><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="10" y="165">test</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="10" y="185">res2</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="50" y="185">=</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="65" y="185">10</text><circle _ngcontent-c9="" class="nea-svg-rect-circle" cx="100" cy="200" r="10"></circle></svg></g>




<g _ngcontent-c6="" nea-sequence-editor-brick="" _nghost-c9="" ng-reflect-item="[object Object]"><!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "false"
}--><!--bindings={
"ng-reflect-ng-if": "true"
}--><svg _ngcontent-c9="" class="nea-svg" x="60" y="410" width="200" height="200"><rect _ngcontent-c9="" class="nea-svg-rect" rx="10" ry="10" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" x="1" y="1" width="198" height="198" style="stroke: rgba(85, 68, 153, 0.867); stroke-width: 4; fill: rgb(0, 114, 187);"></rect><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="#fff" style="cursor:pointer" x="180" y="20">x</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size: 14px" x="10" y="20">System: CheckAbortCycle</text><line _ngcontent-c9="" x1="2" x2="198" y1="30" y2="30" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="stroke: rgba(85, 68, 153, 0.867); stroke-width: 4;"></line><svg _ngcontent-c9="" class="nea-svg-rect-arg" height="200" width="200"><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="130" y="50">Result1</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="10" y="50">Parameter 1 </text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="130" y="70">6</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="10" y="70">Parameter 2: </text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="130" y="90">10</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="10" y="90">Parameter 3: </text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="130" y="110">left</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="10" y="110">Parmeter 4: </text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="130" y="135">Result3</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="10" y="135">Result : </text></svg><line _ngcontent-c9="" x1="2" x2="198" y1="145" y2="145" ng-reflect-ng-style="[object Object]" style="stroke: rgba(85, 68, 153, 0.867); stroke-width: 4;"></line><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="10" y="165">test</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="10" y="185">res2</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="50" y="185">=</text><text _ngcontent-c9="" fill="white" style="font-size:14px" x="65" y="185">10</text><circle _ngcontent-c9="" class="nea-svg-rect-circle" cx="100" cy="200" r="10"></circle></svg></g>
```

I’m trying to select each object, get all field from the boxes and move,

I having problem with xpath and selecting by class.

Do you have a suggestion?

I'm thinking in getting all classes "nea-svg"", the the text of each. After this, i may get all related "nea-sequence-editor-brick". 
As this is a big project, i added a extension go chrome to get xpath and css selectors but, even this fails to retrieve the correct one.

I'm new in protractor and jasmine.

Comment: Try using css selectors. refer<https://ghostinspector.com/blog/css-selector-strategies-automated-browser-testing/>

Comment: can´t open, "Page Not Found". 

I'm thinking in getting all classes "nea-svg"", the the text of each.
After this, i may get all related "nea-sequence-editor-brick".

I'm new in protractor and jasmine. 
As this is a big project, i added a extension go chrome to get xpath and css selectors but, even this fails to retrieve the correct one.

Comment: https://ghostinspector.com/blog/css-selector-strategies-automated-browser-testing/